# how to grab file extension only from a string in php

Tags: php

How can i grab the extension only in a php string?

```
echo $dir.'/'.$file;
```

outputs:  `folder/subfolder1/image.jpg`

so i want to grab only `jpg`

Comment: Will it always be `.jpg` or will it be different?

Comment: there are different extensions; jpg is only an example